# New to Pig : Error 1066, Pig version 0.17.0 Hadoop Version 3.1.0

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have been trying to execute the following command in grunt
.............................................................................................................................................................

```
summerolympic= load '/olympics/input/summer.csv' using PigStorage('\t');

grunt> dump summerolympic
```

.....................................................................................................................................................
which resulted in Error 1066.

```
2018-05-19 00:01:34,684 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2018-05-19 00:01:34,702 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2018-05-19 00:01:34,703 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
2018-05-19 00:01:34,703 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, NestedLimitOptimizer, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
2018-05-19 00:01:34,704 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2018-05-19 00:01:34,705 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2018-05-19 00:01:34,705 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2018-05-19 00:01:34,715 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2018-05-19 00:01:34,717 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2018-05-19 00:01:34,722 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2018-05-19 00:01:34,722 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2018-05-19 00:01:34,726 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - This job cannot be converted run in-process
2018-05-19 00:01:35,221 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/Users/vaisakh/pig-0.17.0/pig-0.17.0-core-h2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp604495205/tmp-331461663/pig-0.17.0-core-h2.jar
2018-05-19 00:01:35,248 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/Users/vaisakh/pig-0.17.0/lib/automaton-1.11-8.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp604495205/tmp-567932277/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2018-05-19 00:01:35,273 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/Users/vaisakh/pig-0.17.0/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp604495205/tmp1847314396/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2018-05-19 00:01:35,297 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/Users/vaisakh/pig-0.17.0/lib/joda-time-2.9.3.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp604495205/tmp-1150759063/joda-time-2.9.3.jar
2018-05-19 00:01:35,301 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2018-05-19 00:01:35,314 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2018-05-19 00:01:35,321 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2018-05-19 00:01:35,524 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader - Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/vaisakh/.staging/job_1526443313382_0005
2018-05-19 00:01:35,527 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2018-05-19 00:01:35,540 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage - Using PigTextInputFormat
2018-05-19 00:01:35,542 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input files to process : 1
2018-05-19 00:01:35,542 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2018-05-19 00:01:35,545 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 1
2018-05-19 00:01:35,994 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - number of splits:1
2018-05-19 00:01:36,025 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Submitting tokens for job: job_1526443313382_0005
2018-05-19 00:01:36,025 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Executing with tokens: []
2018-05-19 00:01:36,029 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner - Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
2018-05-19 00:01:36,270 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl - Submitted application application_1526443313382_0005
2018-05-19 00:01:36,278 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - The url to track the job: http://SSs-MacBook-Air.local:8088/proxy/application_1526443313382_0005/
2018-05-19 00:01:36,278 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_1526443313382_0005
2018-05-19 00:01:36,278 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases summerolympic
2018-05-19 00:01:36,278 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: summerolympic[5,15] C:  R: 
2018-05-19 00:01:36,286 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2018-05-19 00:01:36,286 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1526443313382_0005]
2018-05-19 00:01:46,346 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2018-05-19 00:01:46,346 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_1526443313382_0005 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2018-05-19 00:01:46,346 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2018-05-19 00:01:46,348 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2018-05-19 00:01:46,367 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2018-05-19 00:01:46,384 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2018-05-19 00:01:46,385 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
3.1.0   0.17.0  vaisakh 2018-05-19 00:01:34 2018-05-19 00:01:46 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1526443313382_0005  summerolympic   MAP_ONLY    Message: Job failed!    hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp604495205/tmp-558801235,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/olympics/input/summer.csv"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp604495205/tmp-558801235"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1526443313382_0005


2018-05-19 00:01:46,385 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2018-05-19 00:01:46,389 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias summerolympic
```

Any insights would be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by running in local mode.

$pig -x local